# Creating a database instance after having installed SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: database, ssms, instance

I have installed the SQL Server Management Studio (v. 17.9.1) but I am not able to create an instance.

[image]

In fact no server appears in the box when I browse:

[image]

How can I proceed, step by step, to create a local instance?

Comment: If you installed only the SSMS - then you have **NOTHING** but the management GUI tool - you do ***NOT*** have any SQL Server database engine! That is a separate download that you need to install separately.....

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local Database by using the command prompt. As open cmd with Admin privilege, > sqllocaldb create "database name" -s(start with it) . There is lot of option with sqllocaldb read there.

Comment: This is correct, but IMO, a little incomplete. You'd then need to login to the server with servername "(localdb)\database name"

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows services (services.msc) and check if SQL Server and SQL Server Browser are running. If not, start them and you should be able to login and create the DB.

Answer (score 0):

type in sql server download in your browser and go to microsoft's website. You have downloaded SSMS but you do not have a server installed. Download SQL express or SQL developer edition and install. Once you have done this you will have a default instance (or named if you customized the install). I must have hit this posting 4 times trying to figure this out but now I'm off and running. If you want a test database to play with you can then download adventureworks (again just use your browser (sql adventureworks) and download the backup file. You can restore it by clicking on the databases folder once you have connected to your sql instance in SSMS.